# How to view selenium/phantomjs javascript errors?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, primefaces, error-handling, phantomjs

I'm using phantomJs to run my selenium tests in a headless environment. My tests are coded in Java and Im using the phantomjsdriver as my web driver. One of my tests I believe may be failing do to a javascript error on the page. My test runs perfectly fine in Chrome but fails in phantomjs.

Is there a way to log javascript errors that the phantomjsdriver encounters?

Specifically the web application im automating uses primefaces and phantomjs does not appear to be detecting a ui dialog box that appears.

The page uses the modal dialog module from the link below.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

Phantomjs does show me a screenshot of the timeout as I'm waiting for the dialog to appear and it shows the grey filter over the page as you can see in the primefaces ui demo, but no dialog page element is actually visible. It appears in chrome.